# How to target the second span tag in ul using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

**The Code:**

```
<ul class="site-nav list--inline " id="SiteNav">   
  <li class="site-nav--active">
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link>
      <span class="site-nav__label">HOME</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  **<li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">ORDER NOW</span>
    </a>
  </li>**    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">TRACK ORDER</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">HELP CENTER</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I want to target the SECOND span tag in the list with class: site-nav__label using pure CSS.(nth-child, second-of-type etc.) 
I cannot add ids or classes to this span tag.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried with `nth-child`? Also note your HTML is a little broken, you are missing **"** in the fist `site-nav__link` class.

Answer (score 2):

For select the second `li` try with

```
#SiteNav li:nth-of-type(2)
```

and then for select the span of second li add `span` after:

`#SiteNav li:nth-of-type(2) span`

Comment: #SiteNav li:nth-of-type(2) .site-nav__label -----> This code worked. Thank you! You are a legend!

Comment: @HamidMian no problem, remember you can vote this answer for help other people!

Answer (score 0):

To Target the `span` use a combination of `nth-of-type` and child combinators

```css
#SiteNav > li:nth-of-type(2) > a > span {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}

/*Or Target the span class*/
#SiteNav > li:nth-of-type(2) .site-nav__label {
  font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav list--inline " id="SiteNav">   
  <li class="site-nav--active">
    <!-- Fixed Missing closing " -->
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">HOME</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">ORDER NOW</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">TRACK ORDER</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">HELP CENTER</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

For a good article on nth-child (and nth-of-type) see https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 0):

Because you want inside ul tag, I used ul.site-nav for ul tag with class site-nav

```css
ul.site-nav li:nth-of-type(2) a > span {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav list--inline " id="SiteNav">   
  <li class="site-nav--active">
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link>
      <span class="site-nav__label">HOME</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  **<li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">ORDER NOW</span>
    </a>
  </li>**    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">TRACK ORDER</span>
    </a>
  </li>    
  <li>
    <a href="/" class="site-nav__link">
      <span class="site-nav__label">HELP CENTER</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```